# PHP Ajax request recieves whole html code in response instead of my html tag

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
  Controller:

    public function get_sub_category()
        {
            $id= $this->input->post('id');
            $rec = $this->user_m->get_sub_categories($id);
            $html="";
            if(!empty($rec)) {
                $html .= '<select  name="category" id="category" required />
                <option value="">--Select Sub Vendor--</option>';
                foreach($category as $cat) { 
                    $html .= '<option value="'.$cat->vendor_id.'">'.$cat->vendor_name.'</option>';
                } 
                $html .= '</select>';
            }
            echo $html;
        }
     Model:
     public function get_sub_categories($id)
        {
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('vendor_type');
            $this->db->where('vendor_parent',$id);
            $this->db->order_by('vendor_id','DESC');
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result();
        }

 View:
  <div class="top-row">
            <div class="field-wrap">

              <select  name="category" id="category" required onChange="get_subcategory(this.value);" />
              <option value="">--Select Vendor--</option>
              <?php foreach($category as $cat) { ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $cat->vendor_id; ?>"><?php echo $cat->vendor_name; ?></option>
              <?php } ?>
              </select>
            </div>

            <div class="field-wrap sub_category">

            </div>
          </div> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    function get_subcategory(id) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"<?php echo base_url();?>user/get_sub_category/",
            data: {id:id},
            dataType:"html",
            success: function(response) {
                    alert(response);

            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

In response It alert as my html whole page

```
This is first time I occurred this error for ajax... Couldnt found any proper solution. Page not contained any extra css or extra js. Only 1 js file I used. I removed mimetype from my ajax then also same I am getting same response. I used exit() function at the end of controller but still i was same response.possibilities Im not confirm that jquery_min_js that I am using is right or wrong..response in controller is right or wrong..
```

This is first time I occurred this error for ajax... Unable to found solution. tried lots of time. even datatype and response type is same. 
This is first time I occurred this error for ajax... Couldnt found any proper solution. Page not contained any extra css or extra js. Only 1 js file I used. I removed mimetype from my ajax then also same I am getting same response. I used exit() function at the end of controller but still i was same response.possibilities Im not confirm that jquery_min_js that I am using is right or wrong..response in controller is right or wrong..
This is first time I occurred this error for ajax... Unable to found solution. tried lots of time. even datatype and response type is same.

Comment: If your datatype is HTML, then what do you want to get? And what do you send back to the get_sub_category1() function ?, can you show us your get_sub_category1 function?

Comment: What is the expected output to be received?

Comment: If you receive the wrong response, you're either asking for the wrong resource or the server is sending the wrong response. We aren't in position to tell which is the case.

Comment: Is this a code in drupal?

Comment: Is your code in a php-file or javascript-file?

Comment: Code is in Codeigniter.

Comment: Controller:
public function get_sub_category()
 {
     $id= $this->input->post('id');
     $rec = $this->user_m->get_sub_categories($id);
     $html="";
     if(!empty($rec)) {
         $html .= '<select  name="category" id="category" required />
            <option value="">--Select Sub Vendor--</option>';
            foreach($category as $cat) { 
               $html .= '<option value="'.$cat->vendor_id.'">'.$cat->vendor_name.'</option>';
            } 
            $html .= '</select>';
     }
     echo $html;
 }

Answer (score 0):

If by "I Receive my html page" you mean to receive an entire HTML page into the response variable, I think it has to be with the `dataType` property you've applied.

According to the documentation, `dataType` will convert your response into a proper `text/html` response.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> **dataType** *(default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))*
>   Type: *String*
>   The type of data that you're expecting back from the
>   server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the
>   MIME type of the response

Give it a try without `mimeType` override and `dataType` value to "text" for a plain text string, then adapt these types to suit your needs.